# Column name not working in SQLite Android Studio

Tags: android, database, string, sqlite, identifier

I have the following:

```
public static final String COL_4 = "ID";
```

And:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (LastScore INTEGER, Highscore INTEGER, Title TEXT, ID BOOLEAN)");
```

This works perfectly;

However, if I change ID to, say, "John" (in the declaration and the execSQL),I get the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: John (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Player_Stats SET LastScore=?,Title=?,John=?,Highscore=?
```

Any idea how such a change in the name of the String throw an exception? 
Thank you!

EDIT: The problem is not with Boolean. The same problem happens if I change it to Integer. Works with "ID", doesn't with "John"

Comment: do you want to change column name ID to John ?

Comment: `John` - it's not a column, just a value in it. Please, provide your bind statement

Comment: in your COL_4 ="ID" data type is boolean

Comment: Yes, I want to call my variable COL_4 but I want its value to be "John" rather than "ID". When I do: public static final String COL_4 = "ID"  everything works. When I do: public static final String COL_4 = "John" I get the exception mentioned above

Comment: @RatilalChopda: Yes, it is. I have the same problem if I make it Integer; works with ID, doesn't with "John". I just want to change the column name from ID to John, which will hold boolean values

Comment: @Ziad you mention that ID as column name while creating table ,but while update  you mention that column name is JHON. how it will work dude.

Comment: @Palanivelraghul: No, in fact when I change the column name to John, I change it in the execSQL, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems when I first ran it, the Database was created with the ID column. Hence, I am only calling the onUpgrade() later rather than the onCreate(), which is expecting a column called ID rather than John. I am in the incapability to do this, but I believe deleting the database and starting over will solve the issue. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

**Boolean Data type**

There is no native boolean data type for SQLite. SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Comment: True, but the same happens when I treat it as Integer.